# Gmail API Tutorial only returns Labels

Tags: gmail-api

I've recently been trying to implement the Javascript quick-start guide on the official Google Dev page, which can be found here:

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/js

The example is meant to read your Gmail inbox and display the last 10 emails on your html page. I've gone through the example but after I grant permissions in my web browser, I only see a list of the "labels" present in my inbox with no emails/email content. I have created a new custom label in my Gmail inbox and this new label is view-able on my html page, which to me suggests that my connection to the Gmail API is fine.

However, I have not used Python like the example suggests. My html file is currently being hosted on 000WebHost so I figured I don't need to use Python. The reason I came to this conclusion is because the tutorial explains that Python is used to host a web server, as I'm using 000WebHost I think I don't need to host this web server.

This could be my issue if I've misunderstood what Python is really needed for here?

Other than that, I'm wondering if there are any other glaringly obvious issues to someone experienced with the gmail API?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Actually if you read the tutorial "Print all Labels in the authorized user's inbox."   its meant to print the lables.  it says nothing about displaying emails.   Python is just used to run it hosting will be the same.    If you want to show messages your going to have to edit the tutorial.

Comment: Oh dear you're right, I'm really sorry. I've been trying to get API working using various tutorials recently, I've clearly got them mixed up! Many thanks.